Value is not copying properly in input tag
I am trying to add or edit the form in django by creating customized form using html and css.
Now it works fine for add product form but when i trying edit one of field in the form,image url does  not passing to input tag and when i submit the form it says image tag is empty.
How to recitfy it?
`  
Cake image
     {% if Product.product_img %}
         <img src="{{ Product.product_img }}" alt="Product Image">
     {% endif %}
     <input type="file" name="product_img" accept="image/*" id="product_img">
</div>`


Do you want to download files, like pictures, throw your form or you want add your own picture on form as some kind of print?
